# Not loading or late loading of photos in V-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
<table>
  <tr v-for="row in rowCount">
    <td v-for="col in colCount">
      <img :src="'https://picsum.photos/id/'+colCount+'/200/300'" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return{
        rowCount:2,
        colCount:15
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Hey there,

Normally photos are taken statically with require. But I am giving example from lorem pic. My problem is this: Photos are coming late or not downloading. When i click on another photo the undownloaded downloads and appears on the screen. The item is in the dom, but the photo is not downloaded over the network.

Comment: It already exists, but I couldn't write it because it's a very long series. Normally there is an id number of the photos in the array. According to this id number, I set the photos to the src property of the img with require.

Comment: @DreamBold, you can use v-for to count in a range

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-hooks-7o91f6?file=/src/App.vue:29-32 It seems working correctly @oguzcan You just need add keys

Comment: I have keys. It is not resolved.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The code in your question works perfectly fine, with or without keys.  See the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-for-with-key-forked-gj7m09?file=/src/App.vue) using your exact code from the question (you can ignore the eslint errors for right now -- it is a complaint that you're not using keys).  The image always downloads and displays correctly.